# Multisearch not doing what I expect

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

The message format we chose uses a field called scope to control the level of aggregation you want (by request_type, site, zone, cluster). The scope is set with a dropdown and passed in as a token. I wanted to use multi-search to coalesce the results of 4 different searches. So that if the scope was site, only the results from the site search would be shown.

Actual Search:

```
index=cloud_aws namespace=cloudship lambda=SCScloudshipStepFunctionStats metric_type=*_v0.3 
| spath input=message 
| multisearch 
    [search $request_type_token$ | where "$scope_token$" == "request_type" ] 
    [search $request_type_token$ $site_token$ | where "$scope_token$" == "site"] 
    [search $request_type_token$ $site_token$ $zone_token$ | where "$scope_token$" == "zone"] 
    [search scope=$scope_token$ $request_type_token$ $site_token$ $zone_token$ $cluster_token$ | where "$scope_token$" == "cluster"] 
| timechart cont=FALSE span=$span_token$ sum(success) by request_type
```

Search after token substitution with literal values.

```
index=cloud_aws namespace=cloudship lambda=SCScloudshipStepFunctionStats metric_type=*_v0.3 
| spath input=message 
| multisearch 
    [search request_type="*" 
    | where "site" == "request_type" ]
    [search request_type="*" site="RTP" 
    | where "site" == "site"]
    [search request_type="*" site="RTP" zone="*" 
    | where "site" == "zone"] 
    [search scope=site request_type="*" site="RTP" zone="*" cluster="*" 
    | where "site" == "cluster"] 
| timechart cont=FALSE span=hour sum(success) by request_type
```

BUT ... the results of this query are equivalent to no search at all and I basically do not filter anything.

```
index=cloud_aws namespace=cloudship lambda=SCScloudshipStepFunctionStats metric_type=*_v0.3 
| spath input=message 
| timechart cont=FALSE span=hour sum(success) by request_type
```

This query and the one above give the same result. What am I missing here? When I execute each part of the multi-search separately, the results are correct. I get empty results for all but the 'where "site" == "site"' search. But when I run the whole query I get no filtering at all. Help!

Comment: I want to do this.
```
If scope == 'request':

    search request_type="*"

elif scope == 'site':

    search request_type="*" site=*

scope == 'zone':

    search request_type="*" site=* zone=*

scope == 'cluster':

    search request_type="*" site=* zone=* cluster=*
```
And I just can't make it happen

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/71534191/4418

Answer (score 1):

First, I think what you're looking for is the *value* of `site` to match `request_type` (in the initial `multisearch` `search` line) - but what you're *actually* checking for in the `where` clause is whether the *text* `"site"` equals the *text* `"request_type"`. And, of course, that is not the case!

Start by removing the second line of the `multisearch` (since comparing `site` to `site` will *always* be true), and using `upper()` and `match()`:

```
index=cloud_aws namespace=cloudship lambda=SCScloudshipStepFunctionStats metric_type=*_v0.3 
| spath input=message 
| multisearch 
    [search request_type="*" site=*
    | eval request_type=upper(request_type), site=upper(site)
    | where "site" == "request_type" ]
    [search request_type="*" site="RTP" zone="*" 
    | eval zone=upper(zone), site=upper(site)
    | where match(site,zone)] 
    [search scope=site request_type="*" site="RTP" zone="*" cluster="*"
```

it would be even easier to do `cluster="rtp"` instead of `cluster=*` here, but I've left the idiom of `upper()`ing and `match()`ing for reading consistency

```
    | where match(site,cluster)] 
| timechart cont=FALSE span=hour sum(success) by request_type
```

Comment: Those are just the values passed in after the token is resolved.

Comment: I updated to show what the search actually looks like.

Comment: @StephenDimig - you're still comparing strings to strings, instead of matching the field to a string's contents

Comment: That part is exactly what I want.

Comment: Only one of the seaches should have data. So when "$scope_token$" == "site" I want it to pick that search and all of the others to be empty.

Comment: It is a string to string comparison

Comment: @StephenDimig - there is no point in comparing "string" to "string". That is *always* true. Comparing the *value* of a field to a string makes sense, though. If you want to find the string represented by `$scope_token$` in a field, you do it like this: `| search fieldA="$scope_token$"`