# How to use Splunk functions in the query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Anyone here knows how can I use built-in functions(case) in a Splunk Query? All examples I found were to handle the query results (I can not put it after  eval   or  | )

I need something like.

```
index=case(indexVar == "qa", "qa-all", indexVar == "prod", "prod-all") sourcetype="kube:container:rail-service"
```

OBS I can not just concat the indexVar + "-all"

Comment: Does something like this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71541775/2193968  If I translate that correctly I get `sourcetype="kube:container:rail-service" [| makeresults | eval search=case(indexVar="qa","index=qa-all", indexVar="prod","index=prod-all")  | fields search]`  Let me know if that works...

Comment: If https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652167/2193968 is right something like `((indexVar="qa" index="qa-all") OR (indexVar="prod" index="prod-all")) sourcetype="kube:container:rail-service"` would work

Comment: It didn't really work. How would I use the bar indexVar? I tried with $indexvar$ and didn't work 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `case` function may be built-in, but that doesn't mean you can use it anywhere.  It's only valid with the `eval`, `fieldformat`, and `where` commands.

A workaround would be to put the `eval` in a subsearch.

```
sourcetype="kube:container:rail-service" [ 
  | makeresults 
  | eval index=case(indexVar == "qa", "qa-all", indexVar == "prod", "prod-all") 
  | fields index ]
```

Comment: How it will be considering that the final query should be index ="qa-all"? Anyway it didn't work 

Comment: What does `it didn't work` mean?  What results did you get?  Try running the subsearch (the bit between `[]`) by itself and verify the expected results are returned.  Where does `indexVar` come from?

Comment: To make it easier I am testing it like 

` [ 
  | makeresults 
  | eval index=case("qa" == "qa", "qa-all", "p" == "prod", "prod-all") 
  | fields index ] `

NO results is found.

Comment: Sorry. It actually worked

Comment: how can I use the dashboard token in this query? I am using $indexVar$ but it doesn't work. Your query works fine when I am not using the token.

Comment: The `$indexVar$` syntax is correct.  Check the token name is correct.  Of course, tokens are not present when running a query in a Search box.

Comment: This is the final query that worked for me when applied to a dashboard

`sourcetype="kube:container:rail-service" [ 
  | makeresults 
  | eval index=case("$indexVar$" == "qa", "qa-all", "$indexVar$" == "prod", "prod-all") 
  | fields index ]`


The missing part was the `""` around the variable